# VS Code: Case sensitive replacement after pressing Crtl - D

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Let's suppose I have the following code:

[image]

But I change my mind and I don't want to call it `plan` anymore. I want to call it `schedule`. So, because VS Code is so amazing and I'm so lazy, I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> hoping for VS Code to change the name respecting the case. But suddenly:

[image]

Is it there any way to tell VS Code to respect the case?

Comment: FYI [Alfred's answer buried below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60950629/80428) is an *exact* solution to the question.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

With 1.37 (July 2019), it is possible through a find/replace (which now can replace by preserving case).

- [Issue 9798](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9798) has been implemented by [PR 78003](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/78003).
- [issue 78397](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78397) has been implemented by [PR 79111](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/79111) (1.38 only) for *search*/replace.

From [1.37 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_37#_preserve-case-in-find-and-replace):

> You can now preserve case when doing replacement in the editor's Find widget. The feature is turned on when the Preserve Case option (AB button) is turned on in the editor's Replace input box.

[image: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_37/preserve-case-button.png]

> Currently VS Code only supports preserve Full Upper Case, Full Lower Case, and Title Case.

Comment: Slight typo in first line: s/b `find/replace` .  Same functionality was added to `search/replace` in v1.38 - see other answer (including hyphenated word preserve case).

Comment: This only works with actually using the "find-replace" widget. not by using multi-cursor (ctrl-D), which the Question was about

Comment: @FreTimmerman I agree. This answer was proposed as an alternative to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. An alternative which does respect the case.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to achieve this without using the find/replace menu, there is an extension which solves your problem: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Cardinal90.multi-cursor-case-preserve

Comment: EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thanks! IMHO this should be part of the core features of the IDE.

Comment: This exactly addresses the question, amazing find @Alfred! I've left a comment on the question as this answer deserves more attention!

Answer (score 19):

Shortcuts are <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for case sensitive. There is a little toolbar appears at the top-right corner of the VS Code, to let you toggle search options.

[image]

or you just  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to toggle replace mode.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. This only selects things that match the case, but I (and I believe OP) want to know how to respect the case when changing it, so you can write "plan" or "Plan" and still get "oldPlanName" and "plan.Name"

Comment: @MattFletcher just switch do case sensitive, then select all "plan" with Ctrl+D and write "schedule", then select all "Plan" with Ctrl+D and write "Schedule"

Comment: @mos I think we all know how to do that. But it's nice to be able to do it all at once.

Answer (score 13):

The v1.38 release in early September will extend the `Preserve Case` functionality to replacements while searching across files using the **Search Panel**.  See [add Preserve Case to Searches (all files)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78397).

[image: Search Preserve Case demo].

> There is also a new case preservation mode for hyphen-separated words.
>
> v1.39 is adding preserve case for _underscore separated words. Like foo_bar.

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/79660

[image: hyphenated words and case preservation]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it isn't, a workaround could be using the buttons that appear on top right after you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. The second lets you select occurrences respecting the case, this way you could replace the text in 2 steps, first `Plan` and then `plan`.

Comment: Yes, I know, but the idea is to be able to do it in one go. It would be great.

Answer (score 2):

So select the code bit, ctrl+h to open replace, edit find and replace, turn off match case in find, turn on preserve case within replace, Alt+L to find all occurences in selection, and Ctrl+Alt+Enter to execute.

9/10 cases you'll get it wrong, doesn't worth the effort. Just use ctr+d, then do the same for the uppercase.

Personally looking forward for a simpler/safer solution through the ctrl+d way. :)