# In VScode, how to select matches only in a region?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example, when selecting "Something" in the first button, the second and third are automatically selected in VScode, if pressed Cmd+Shift+L(On mac). But how to only select the "Something" in the first two button, but not the third one?

```html
<button>
    Something
</button>
    
<button>
    Something
</button>

<button>
    Something
</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code: Case sensitive replacement after pressing Crtl - D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237358/vs-code-case-sensitive-replacement-after-pressing-crtl-d)

Comment: Select the part and Ctrl + d

Comment: There is a `Find in Selection` option in the Ctrl+F Find Widget.

Comment: Crtl d works, but how to select the previous?

Comment: select the first and then `Ctrl+D`